# Compare names in two data frames

Tags: r, compare

I have two data frames, `F` and `M` with rows of names (First, Middle and Surname). I'd like to find which rows are in both data frames.

```
F <- read.table(
  text = "First   Middle Surname
  Alessio  Antonin    Smith
  Alessio  Antonio    Smith
  Alessio    Carlo    Smith
  Alessio  Claudio    Smith
  Alessio    Diego    Smith
  Alessio Emiliano    Smith", header = TRUE)


M <- read.table(
  text = "First  Middle Surname
  Alessio Lorenzo    Smith
  Alessio  Miguel    Smith
  Alessio  Rafael    Smith
  Alessio Santino    Smith
  Alessio    Vito    Smith
  Claudio Alessio    Smith", header = TRUE)
```

`compare(F,M)` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: In future, please post the output from `dput(head(F))` and `dput(head(M))` instead of this. We can't copy and paste this into R

Comment: `FM <- rbind(F, M); unique(FM[duplicated(FM),])` will do it

Comment: @RAB Many thanks for your answer. To read in data into R via the clipboard: M<- read.table(pipe("pbpaste"), sep="", header=T) on Mac or M<- read.table("clipboard", sep="", header=T) on windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a merge on all columns.

```
A <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 21:30, c = 31:40)
B <- data.frame(a = 9:15, b = 29:35, c = 39:45)


merge(A, B)# implicit by = names(A) since all columns are common (thanks Rich Scriven)

#    a  b  c
# 1 10 30 40
# 2  9 29 39
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have these dataframes:

```
 F <- data.frame(First=c("A", "B", "C"), 
                 Middle=c("A", "C", "C"), 
                 Last=c("D", "E", "F"))

 M <- data.frame(First=c("B", "B", "C"), 
                 Middle=c("J", "J", "C"),
                 Last=c("F", "S", "F"))
```

Then using `dplyr::intersect` you can get the common elements per columns:

```
 intersect(F, M)
 # First Middle Last
 #   C      C    F
```

Alternatively you can turn the datframe into 1 vector and use `intersect` again to get the matches over the whole dataframe

To get the whole row you can use this:

```
 F <- F %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(All=paste(First, Middle, Last))
 M <- M %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(All=paste(First, Middle, Last))
 intersect(F$All, M$All)
```